# C# Loop round a Range.Value which has 2 objects [0,0] to find if string = variable

Tags: c#, object, loops, aspose

I am using `Aspose.Cells` and I have created a Range of cells. This range produces a `range.Value` which consists of 2 objects [row,column]. I now want to loop round these objects which in my case  is 1 row and 33 columns with each column having a string 'day' inserted.

So basically I want to loop round and add an if statement such as

```
          if (range.Value.ToString() == "Sat")
            {
                range.ApplyStyle(backgroundColour, flg);
            }
```

Do I someway have to loop the 33 objects(columns)?

Each range value expression looks like `((object[,])(range.Value))[0, 0]`  whew the value in this case is Fri and then `((object[,])(range.Value))[0, 1]` where the value is Sat and so on.

Comment: a commercial product that uses object[,] for cell should be banned :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the whole range like this:

```
    object[,] rng = (object[,])range.Value;

    for (int row = rng.GetLowerBound(0); row <= rng.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
    {
        for (int day = rng.GetLowerBound(1); day <= rng.GetUpperBound(1); day++)
        {
            string dayName = rng[row,day] as string;
        }
    }
```